# MS ACCESS Update column to null if current value falls within date range

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I'm having trouble updating a column to null if the values fall within a certain year range. I was able to select for these records, but the UPDATE statement is not working. This is the code I have.

```
UPDATE donors SET dob = NULL
WHERE YEAR(dob) > (YEAR(Date()) - 18) OR YEAR(dob) < 1930;
```

A SELECT statement with that condition works fine. The UPDATE will give me an "Invalid procedure call" error.

Comment: Perhaps `dob` doesn't accept _Null_ values.

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant ")" before the subtraction:

```
UPDATE donors SET dob = NULL
WHERE YEAR(dob) > (YEAR(dob) - 18) OR YEAR(dob) < 1930;
-- ")" Removed here--------^
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It was supposed to be YEAR(DATE()). I fixed in the original post.